# String printing extra values C programming

Tags: c, string, string.h

I am currently working on a game in class but have some problems when printing and checking strings. Essentially it is hang man and I need to print the word as just `_` (underscores) with spaces separating each underscore. I am just filling in a skeleton code and the code I had to fill in looks like:

```
initializeBlankString(const int numLetter, char revealedLetters[25])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i < numLetter; i++){
    revealedLetters[i] = '_';
  }
 revealedLetters[numLetter - 1] = '\0';
}

printWithSpaces(char revealedLetters[25])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<(strlen(revealedLetters));i++){
    printf("%c ", revealedLetters[i]);
  } 
}

revealGuessedLetter(char word[], char revealedLetters[25], char guess)
{
  int i, n = 0;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){
    if (word[i] == guess){
      revealedLetters[i] = guess;
      n = 1;
    }
  }
  return n;
}

checkGuess(char word[25], char revealedLetters[25])
{
  if(word == revealedLetters)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried lots of different things and I am unable to be successful.
The problems would is when the word is something like unix it will show `_ _ _ _ + r 6 _` instead of just `_ _ _ _` I escaped I thought but it doesn't look like it.

Function calls look like this:

```
initializeBlankString(strlen(word), revealedLetters);
printWithSpaces(revealedLetters);
charRevealed = revealGuessedLetter(word, revealedLetters, guess);
won = checkGuess(word, revealedLetters);
```

solution:

```
void initializeBlankString(const int numLetter, char revealedLetters[25])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i < numLetter; i++){
    revealedLetters[i] = '_';
  }
 revealedLetters[numLetter] = '\0';
}

void printWithSpaces(char revealedLetters[25])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<(strlen(revealedLetters));i++){
    printf("%c ", revealedLetters[i]);
  } 
}

int revealGuessedLetter(char word[], char revealedLetters[25], char guess)
{
  int i, n = 0;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){
    if (word[i] == guess){
      revealedLetters[i] = guess;
      n = 1;
    }
  }
  return n;
}

int checkGuess(char word[25], char revealedLetters[25])
{
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word);i++){
    if(word[i] != revealedLetters[i])
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: GDB or any other debugger is your best friend here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position for the final `'\0'` is miscalculated in `initializeBlankString`:

```
revealedLetters[numLetter - 1] = '\0';
```

Should be:

```
revealedLetters[numLetter] = '\0';
```

There are many more problems with your code:

- Modern C mandates function return types.  `void` for the first 2, `int` for the last 2.
- You cannot compare char arrays with `if(word == revealedLetters)`

Comment: Thank you, I knew about the whole int and void types but they way they worded their document it made it seem that they weren't needed here. Anyways, thank you got it figured out. As for the char array comparison I just made a for loop that checks each character against each other and if all match then return 1 otherwise return 0.